# Script won't iterate through text files in folder

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-2.7, iteration

Would anyone be able to tell me why the script won't iterate through each text file? The script runs successfully (Python 2.7), but does not populate GasLines_Final polyline feature class with features from each txt file (each txt file resides in PipelinesTxtFiles folder)

```py
import arcpy

# access module to work with ARCGIS
import os

# access OS to access txt files
from arcpy import env

# access environment in ARCGIS

env.workspace = (
    "C:/School/SHSU Fall 2022/GEOG5367_GISProgramming/FinalProject/final_project_data/"
)
# set workspace
env.overwriteOutput = True
# turn overwriting on

outpath = "C:/School/SHSU Fall 2022/GEOG5367_GISProgramming/FinalProject/final_project_data/PipelineAnalysis.gdb/"
# set outpath to GDB to store outputs on LOCAL MACHINE

if not arcpy.Exists(outpath):
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(
        "C:/School/SHSU Fall 2022/GEOG5367_GISProgramming/FinalProject/final_project_data/",
        "PipelineAnalysis.gdb",
    )
# Create a GDB if one does not exist already

spat_ref = "C:/School/SHSU Fall 2022/GEOG5367_GISProgramming/FinalProject/final_project_data/Gas_Lines.shp"
# use provided Gas_Lines shp spatial reference for this process

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(
    outpath,
    "GasLines_Final",
    "POLYLINE",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "C:/School/SHSU Fall 2022/GEOG5367_GISProgramming/FinalProject/final_project_data/Gas_Lines.shp",
)
# create polyline feature class 'GasLines_Final'
arcpy.AddField_management("PipelineAnalysis.gdb/GasLines_Final", "NAME", "TEXT")
# add a new 'NAME' field to GasLines_Final to store NAME of pipeline built, from txt files
arcpy.AddField_management("PipelineAnalysis.gdb/GasLines_Final", "DATE", "TEXT")
# add a new 'DATE' field to GasLines_Final to store DATE pipeline was created, from txt files
arcpy.AddField_management("PipelineAnalysis.gdb/GasLines_Final", "PSI", "TEXT")
# add a new 'PSI' field to store PSI of pipeline, from txt files; NOTE: PSI was not included in txt files
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(
    "PipelineAnalysis.gdb/GasLines_Final", ["SHAPE@", "NAME", "DATE", "PSI"]
)
# Create an insert cursor for inputting geometry info and field info into GasLines_Final
print("GasLines_Final empty feature class created...")

array = arcpy.Array()
# array for coordinates
point = arcpy.Point()
# create vertex from each coordinate in the line
print("Array defined")
print("Points defined")

name = ""
# emptry string populated from each pipeline NAME from txt file
date = ""
# empty string populated from each new pipeline DATE from txt file
psi = ""
# empty string populated from each new pipeline PSI as it's found; NOTE: PSI not included in txt file
print("Empty lists created")


PipelineFiles = os.listdir(
    "C:/School/SHSU Fall 2022/GEOG5367_GISProgramming/FinalProject/final_project_data/PipelineTxtFiles"
)  # set a variable to call list of Pipeline txt files
# loop through the text files in PipelineTxtFiles folder in my LOCAL MACHINE
for file in PipelineFiles:
    # open PipelineTxtFiles
    txtFile = open(
        "C:/School/SHSU Fall 2022/GEOG5367_GISProgramming/FinalProject/final_project_data/PipelineTxtFiles/{}".format(
            file
        ),
        "r+",
    )
    for line in txtFile:  # loop through each open text file
        splitline = line.split(" ")  # convert each line into a list of the words
        if splitline[0] == "Work":
            date = splitline[3]  # if the first word = work, change date to new date
        elif splitline[0] == "Spatial":
            spatialreference = arcpy.Describe(
                spat_ref
            ).spatialReference  # define spatial reference of pipeline
        elif splitline[0] == "Name:":
            name = splitline[
                1
            ]  # if the first word = Name:, change name of gasline to new gas line name
        elif splitline[0] == "PSI":
            psi = splitline[
                1
            ]  # if the first word = PSI, change PSI variable to new psi; NOTE: PSI info not included in txt files
        elif splitline[0] == "\n":
            polyline = arcpy.Polyline(
                array
            )  # if line is blank, create a polyline out of the array
            cursor.insertRow(
                [polyline, name, date, psi]
            )  # insert polyline, gasline name, gasline date, and gasline PSI into GasLines_Final
            array = (
                arcpy.Array()
            )  # reset the array, so a new array is created when the current file is done being used
        else:
            ex = splitline[0]  # select the first word in x-point
            point.X = ex[:-1]  # remove the comma from end of x-point
            point.Y = splitline[1]  # select the second word in y-point
            array.add(point)  # add the x,y point to the array
    txtFile.close()  # close the open text file

del cursor
# delete the cursor

fc_projection = spatialreference

print("Spatial reference is {}".format(spatialreference.name))
# print("spatial reference, so user knows what is being used, and if it needs to change")

print(
    "GasLines_Final finished creating... Check results in GasLines_Final feature class in PipelineAnalysis.gdb"
)
# print("message letting user know process was complete")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import arcpy

# access module to work with ARCGIS
import os
import glob

# access OS to access txt files
from arcpy import env

# access environment in ARCGIS
basedir = (
    "C:/School/SHSU Fall 2022/GEOG5367_GISProgramming/FinalProject/final_project_data"
)

env.workspace = basedir
# set workspace
env.overwriteOutput = True
# turn overwriting on


outpath = os.path.join(basedir, "PipelineAnalysis.gdb")
# set outpath to GDB to store outputs on LOCAL MACHINE

if not arcpy.Exists(outpath):
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(
        basedir,
        "PipelineAnalysis.gdb",
    )
# Create a GDB if one does not exist already

spat_ref = os.path.join(basedir, "Gas_Lines.shp")
# use provided Gas_Lines shp spatial reference for this process

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(
    outpath,
    "GasLines_Final",
    "POLYLINE",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    os.path.join(basedir, "Gas_Lines.shp"),
)
# create polyline feature class 'GasLines_Final'
arcpy.AddField_management("PipelineAnalysis.gdb/GasLines_Final", "NAME", "TEXT")
# add a new 'NAME' field to GasLines_Final to store NAME of pipeline built, from txt files
arcpy.AddField_management("PipelineAnalysis.gdb/GasLines_Final", "DATE", "TEXT")
# add a new 'DATE' field to GasLines_Final to store DATE pipeline was created, from txt files
arcpy.AddField_management("PipelineAnalysis.gdb/GasLines_Final", "PSI", "TEXT")
# add a new 'PSI' field to store PSI of pipeline, from txt files; NOTE: PSI was not included in txt files
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(
    "PipelineAnalysis.gdb/GasLines_Final", ["SHAPE@", "NAME", "DATE", "PSI"]
)
# Create an insert cursor for inputting geometry info and field info into GasLines_Final
print("GasLines_Final empty feature class created...")

array = arcpy.Array()
# array for coordinates
point = arcpy.Point()
# create vertex from each coordinate in the line
print("Array defined")
print("Points defined")

name = ""
# emptry string populated from each pipeline NAME from txt file
date = ""
# empty string populated from each new pipeline DATE from txt file
psi = ""
# empty string populated from each new pipeline PSI as it's found; NOTE: PSI not included in txt file
print("Empty lists created")


PipelineFiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(basedir, "PipelineTxtFiles", "*.txt"))

# loop through the text files in PipelineTxtFiles folder in my LOCAL MACHINE
for file in PipelineFiles:
    # open PipelineTxtFiles
    with open(file, "r+") as txtFile:
        for line in txtFile:  # loop through each open text file
            # convert each line into a list of the words
            splitline = line.split(" ")
            if splitline[0] == "Work":
                # if the first word = work, change date to new date
                date = splitline[3]
            elif splitline[0] == "Spatial":
                # define spatial reference of pipeline
                spatialreference = arcpy.Describe(spat_ref).spatialReference
            elif splitline[0] == "Name:":
                # if the first word = Name:, change name of gasline to new gas line name
                name = splitline[1]
            elif splitline[0] == "PSI":
                # if the first word = PSI, change PSI variable to new psi; NOTE: PSI info not included in txt files
                psi = splitline[1]
            elif splitline[0] == "\n":
                # if line is blank, create a polyline out of the array
                polyline = arcpy.Polyline(array)
                # insert polyline, gasline name, gasline date, and gasline PSI into GasLines_Final
                cursor.insertRow([polyline, name, date, psi])
                # reset the array, so a new array is created when the current file is done being used
                array = arcpy.Array()
            else:
                ex = splitline[0]  # select the first word in x-point
                point.X = ex[:-1]  # remove the comma from end of x-point
                point.Y = splitline[1]  # select the second word in y-point
                array.add(point)  # add the x,y point to the array

del cursor
# delete the cursor

fc_projection = spatialreference

print("Spatial reference is {}".format(spatialreference.name))
# print("spatial reference, so user knows what is being used, and if it needs to change")

print(
    "GasLines_Final finished creating... Check results in GasLines_Final feature class in PipelineAnalysis.gdb"
)
# print("message letting user know process was complete")
```

`os.listdir` is probably not the way to go for listing files as it will also list directories.

You'd better use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to search for file using pattern matching.

Also, store your base directory as a variable and use `os.path.join` to construct subfolders instead of typing the full path again and again. It's error prone.

In addition, you'd better use a [context manager](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/context-manager-in-python/) when opening files.

Finally, use brackets with print. Even with Python 2.